# How to replace nth char from a string in Go

Tags: string, go, replace

I want to replace the nth char in the original string. I can access the nth char from the string by using `chars[i]`, but when I assign a value to `chars[i]`, I get an error.

```
package main
import "fmt"

func main() {
  var chars = "abcdef"
  fmt.Println(string(chars[3]))
  chars[3] = "z" // is not working
}
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This is happening because `chars` is actually a string and is immutable. If you declared it appropriately (as a byte slice) then you can assign to it as you're attempting. Here's an example;

```
package main
import "fmt"

func main() {
  var chars = []byte{'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f'}
  fmt.Println(string(chars[3]))
  fmt.Printf("%T\n", chars)
  chars[3] = 'z'
  fmt.Println(string(chars))
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/N1sSsfIBQY

Alternately you could use reslicing as demonstrated in the other answer.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation and very good answer, this is what I'm looking for. but do I need to convert my string to byte array?

Comment: @PankajKhairnar yeah here's another example that does that... https://play.golang.org/p/M_Gb1_bVCs basically if you ahve a string `s` you can just do `myBytes := []byte(s)`

Comment: Thank you so much, it make sense now :)

Comment: @PankajKhairnar also, I left in that random `fmt.Printf("%T\n", myInstance)` bit, that can be useful as `%T` prints the type information. In this case I added it to double check the type of `chars`

Comment: Beware this won't work for Unicode strings as characters may use more than one byte. Use []rune instead of []byte.

Answer (score 27):

Strings are immutable.

```
chars = chars[:3] + "z" + chars[4:]
```

Answer (score 3):

Using the index operator `[]` on a string [yields `byte`](https://go.dev/ref/spec#String_types):

> A string's bytes can be accessed by integer indices 0 through len(s)-1.

so the naive approach of indexing the string directly will work only if it just happens to contain only single-byte characters.

A more solid solution is to convert the string to rune slice:

```
func replaceAt(s string, i int, c rune) string {
    r := []rune(s)
    r[i] = c
    return string(r)
}
```

Which will work nicely with arbitrary UTF-8 input:

```
package main

import "fmt"

var chars = "abcdef"
var multibyte = "由汉字组成的一句话"

func main() {
    v := replaceAt(chars, 3, 'z')
    fmt.Println(v) // abczef

    w := replaceAt(multibyte, 3, 'z')
    fmt.Println(w) // 由汉子z成的一句话
}

func replaceAt(s string, i int, c rune) string {
    r := []rune(s)
    r[i] = c
    return string(r)
}
```

Playground: https://go.dev/play/p/wKtYIkIXw4Z

Answer (score 2):

Use slice indexing to remove the character at the index, and place a new character there instead.

```
package main
import "fmt"

func main() {
  var chars = "abcdef"
  fmt.Println(string(chars[3]))
  chars = chars[:3] + "z" + chars[3+1:]
  fmt.Println(string(chars[3]))
}
```

Output:

```
d
z
```

`[:3]` selects everything in the slice from the beginning up until the index 3, and [3+1:] selects everything from the index (3+1) until the end of the slice. Put the character you wanted in-between the two statements and cat them all together for the effect of replacing a character at a specific index.

If you want to replace a specific character (i.e. all (or some of) the instances of the letter 'b') you can use the [strings.Replace](https://golang.org/pkg/strings/#Replace) function.

Comment: it works for both idx == 0 and idx == len(chars) - 1.
Check the playground: https://play.golang.org/p/6eLp1C9PX23