# cannot assign to v[i], reference to array problem?

Tags: go

I am trying to solve a puzzle to practice my Go. But, I am a little stuck and the error is not very helpful.

> ./prog.go:22:23: cannot assign to v[j]
>
> ./prog.go:22:23: cannot assign to v[wLen - 1 - j]

```
func SpinWords(str string) string {
    ws := strings.Split(str, " ")
    for i := 0; i < len(ws); i++ {
        v := ws[i]
        wLen := len(v)

        if wLen > 4 {
            for j := 0; j < wLen/2; j++ {
                v[j], v[wLen-1-j] = v[wLen-1-j], v[j]
            }
            ws[i] = v
        }
    }

    return strings.Join(ws, " ")
}
```

Almost working code here: https://play.golang.org/p/j9BYk642bFa

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Golang : How to replace nth char from a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37688457/golang-how-to-replace-nth-char-from-a-string)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't assign to elements of `v` because `v` is a string and strings are immutable. You can convert the string to a `[]byte` first, and then work with the elements of it, but it is not safe if your strings contain multi-byte characters.

```
v:=[]byte(ws[i])
```

Or you can convert the string to a `[]rune` and work with it:

```
v:=[]rune(ws[i])
```

Then you can assign to elements of `v`, and when you're done, convert it back to a string:

```
str:=string(v)
```

Comment: Ah, of course. That makes sense. Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to performed the action then you have to convert word from string to []rune

This code works :)

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "strings"
)

func main() {
    result := SpinWords("Welcome to the jungle we got fun and games")

    fmt.Println(result)
}

func SpinWords(str string) string {
    ws := strings.Split(str, " ")
    for i := 0; i < len(ws); i++ {
        v := ws[i]
        wLen := len(v)

        if wLen > 4 {
            vinrune := []rune(v)
            for j := 0; j < wLen/2; j++ {
                vinrune[j], vinrune[wLen-1-j] = vinrune[wLen-1-j], vinrune[j]
            }
            v = string(vinrune)
            ws[i] = v
        }
    }

    return strings.Join(ws, " ")
}
```